# IDL.json for Voting

Tags: anchor

Is there an idl.json file for [voting](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/programs/vote)? The purpose would be to compile instructions in languages like Golang to do staking and set up voting accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the anchor program for this example at [examples.anchor-lang](https://examples.anchor-lang.com/docs/onchain-voting).

Just run `anchor build` from the project directory and find the idl file in `target/idl` folder.

Comment: This is not the Solana vote account, stake, and delegation instruction though.  This is a totally separate, unrelated voting scheme for people, no?

Answer (score 0):

There might not be one since that program was written before Anchor, and IDLs.

You can clone the program and generate one though using Metaplex's [shank](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/shank).